# efficient use of a bin/exe

Tags: unix

I have a program i wrote in c++ and shared the executable with a client. The program basically uses some third party security libraries to generate a code give an input value.

as a test we provided them a list of 2million inputs. they are writing a script in unix that is opening the file reading the inputs and loading the executable each time with the input parameter.

This is a one time thing, however they are asking if there is any other efficient way of doing this via scripting. Just curious if there was a way in unix to speed up this process.

Here is the following unix script they are using....
anything here that is inefficient that they can use which will make it faster?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
for input in `cat test_input.txt` 
do 
echo ${input} `my_script${input}` 
done 
# The End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a unix shell script, but a scripting language like python also works for this type of thing (and it's on most unix based computers by default).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        retcode = subprocess.call(['execname', line])
        print retcode
```

You can also have it pipe stdout and/or stderr if you want.

Comment: can you take a look at the script i have and see if there is a way to make it more efficient? like are there any operations like cat that is causing it to be slow?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can probably make it faster by having it spawn one process per core continuously, but this isn't nearly as easy to do (and is only worth it if the program your spawning is going to take awhile, and probably not worth it for a one off program).